# Adjust script that deletes files older than 30 days on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this script that deletes old files from Google Drive ... I would like to adjust it so that it deletes files from a specific folder, specifically files that were created over 3 hours ago. And one more detail, the folder cannot be empty, so the latest file even if it has been published for more than 3 hours cannot be deleted. It can only be deleted when another file is added in the folder. I need help getting this done, I can't edit the script for these details.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];
  // Old date is 30 days
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*24*30;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to delete the files which are `modifiedDate < 3 hours`.
- There are the files in the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- When the document of [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files) is seen, for `modifiedDate`, it seems that the ISO format is required to be used.

When above point and `modifiedDate < 3 hours` are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*24*30;
var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

#### To:

```
var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files)
- [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added 1:

- You want to delete the files which are `modifiedDate < 3 hours`.
- There are the files in the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- **You want to leave the newest created file.**

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function of `getOldFileIDs()` as follows.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 30 days
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  obj.sort(function(x, y) {return x.date < y.date ? 1 : -1});
  obj.shift();
  var fileIDs = obj.map(function(e) {return e.id});
  return fileIDs;
};
```

- In this modified script, the retrieved files are sorted by the date and the top of element of the array is deleted. By this, the file IDs except for the newest created file are returned.

### Added 2:

- You want to completely delete the files without moving to trashbox.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function of `deleteFiles()` as follows. Before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

From:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
```

To:

```
Drive.Files.remove(fileId);
```

- **By this modification, the file ID is completely deleted. So when you test this, please be careful.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation ... What is still in doubt is whether there is any way the folder will never be empty, that there is always at least 1 file, even if it has more than 3 hours of creation. The folder cannot be empty. The most recent file must always remain even if it is old (3 hours or more of creation).

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I have to apologize that my proposed script was not useful for your situation. From your replying, you want to leave the newest created file. I could understand like this. By this, I proposed one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: On the matter of leaving only 1 file I can assure you that it worked in a few hours, because for now there are several files created with less than 3 hours. I'll be back here to tell you if it worked.

But from what I saw, it's working perfectly, I've created a trigger that will be activated every 30 minutes to be able to delete the old files.

May I enjoy and ask you one more thing? When files go to the trash, do they consume google drive memory? If so, is there any way to permanently delete files without being in the trash? I am afraid to fill the capacity that is 5 gigabytes.

Comment: Thank you so much for being willing to help, you have no idea how much this will make my day to day work easier! Very glad you showed up.

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I added one more modified script for completely deleting the files. Could you please confirm it? When you test this, please be careful.

Comment: Good morning mate. Everything worked very well until this morning. Did not really delete the latest file. However, when the trigger was activated every 5 minutes, at some time it did not delete files that literally had more than 3 hours of creation. sometimes he would delete it after 3.5 hours, sometimes 4 hours or more. It did not seem constant, the time here in Brazil is GMT-3, can this affect in any way?

Comment: And another thing, today new files have been added and the one that was left alone yesterday is not being deleted, it is still there, even though it has been created for 10 hours. Could it be because it was created yesterday and the script calculation can only analyze today's date?

Comment: Image to file not removed: ibb.co/jfW3cF2

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for your replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new situation and about your image from your replying. I cannot think of the issue from the information of replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But I would like to confirm the detail of it. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information of your new situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. And also I think that your new situation and discussions of it will be useful for other users. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Frederico Mattos I could confirm that the search query worked and the returned `fileIDs` is the files except for the latest one, again. I cannot understand about your image in your replying. From this situation, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So could you please post it as new question by including the detail information for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to think of the issue. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: I also have problems with English, I'm Brazilian. My natural language is Portuguese. I have to use the translator. But look, the delay in deleting the files only happened once. Today all day worked perfectly, I believe it was some failure to update my Google Drive, which was showing the file but in fact it had already been deleted. The operation is perfect, you do not need to edit anything. Thank you so much for everything!

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I would like to try to replicate your current situation. When I achieved it and found the solution and workaround, I would like to tell you. In the current stage, I have to apologize I cannot still replicate your situation.

Comment: No problem mate!